# How do I move multiple nodes at once in a TJvTreeView?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

When you select multiple nodes of a JvTreeView, and then try to drag these nodes, the JvTreeView selects the node you clicked to drag, rather than initiating dragging **all** the selected nodes. You end up dragging only this single node.

Is it possible to drag multiple nodes in a JvTreeView? I am using Delphi 2007.

**UPDATE:** Oddly enough, if I hold down CTRL+SHIFT when dragging the items, I can successfully drag them all. Any ideas?

Comment: @David: Isn't that a bit harsh? It's not like MultiSelect is something that is specific to Delphi's TTreeView implementation...

Comment: Is TJvTreeView a JEDI component? And what does it offer over TTreeView?

Comment: Yes, it is a JEDI component. The advantages are that it has built in support for adding and managing Checkboxes. At least that is why I am using it.

Comment: @David - Reason for my usage is the `TJvDBTreeView`, the data-aware counterpart.

Comment: @Sertac Perhaps I'm the only Delphi developer who does ever do anything with databases!!

Comment: The reason dragging works when you hold ctrl shift is probably that holding either of them down while clicking is a way to extend the selection of nodes or items in other controls. Shift-click being the default way to select a contiguous set of nodes/items, ctrl-click being the default way to select (non-contiguous) single nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `MultiSelectStyle` is the default `[msControlSelect]`, then the answer to your question is *'you don't release the control key when you're selecting the last item and beginning dragging'*.

The culprit is in `TJvTreeView.WMLButtonDown` in `JvComCtrls.pas`. Code there tests if 'Ctrl' is pressed when the TreeView is MultiSelect, and clears all items and selects the clicked item if 'Ctrl' is not pressed. It should instead test if the clicked item is already selected and do nothing if it is.

You can see the *broken* behavior without dragging. Multi select a few items and then click a selected item with the mouse. The VCL TreeView do not select or de-select anything, while the JVTreeView, instead, de-selects all items and selects the clicked one.

Comment: any suggestions on how to modify that function to allow the user to simply drag highlighted nodes?

Comment: @Mick - Find the `ClearSelection;` `SelectItem(Node)` statements near the end of the procedure, and surround the two statements with `if not IsNodeSelected(Node) then begin` and an `end;`. But keep in mind that this has the additional side effect of `OnSelectionChange` not firing when selecting an already selected item. This is good IMO, but if you think otherwise, well, you can suit the code to your needs. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes absolutely, I do it all the time.

Of course Multi-Select needs to be True and you may need to have a look at the TTreeView's MultiSelectStyle. That controls what type of nodes can be selected at the same time. For example if msSiblingOnly is set to true, you can only select sibblings.

Are you using dmAutomatic or dmManual. If the latter, it could be that you are doing something in the OnMouse* events that is negating the multi-selection you made earlier.

Comment: I apologize, this should read JvTreeView, not the standard TreeView!

Comment: Ah, in that case, I guess the answer would still be along the same lines as I cannot imagine the jvcl treeview not being able to do this, but as I don't use jvTreeView, I cannot say for certain.